# Chrome80 & WDIO : Chrome option --lang not working on ubuntu

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Chrome80 & WDIO : Chrome option --lang not working on ubuntu.

It worked on Chrome78 & ubuntu.
It worked on Chrome80 & Mac.
It NOT worked on Chrome80 & ubuntu.

```
chromeOptions: {
    args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', 'window-size=1920,1080', '--lang=ja', '--no-sandbox']
},
```

I try this. but not work.

```
chromeOptions: {
    args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', 'window-size=1920,1080', '--no-sandbox'],
    prefs: {
        'intl.accept_languages': 'ja'
    }
},
```

### Version:

Ubuntu:18.04
Chrome,ChromeDriver:80
WDIO:4

Comment: Ubuntu runs on Docker.

Comment: I try this. but not work.
        'intl.app_locale': 'ja'